# How to take a screenshot of a MSAccess ControlTip Text in Form View

Tags: ms-access-2010

Problem:  On an MSAccess Form, a field is moused-over, the ControlTip Text appears.  You want to take a screenshot of it to insert in a manual, etc.  You hold down the Ctrl key + Print Screen and the ControlTip Text disappears.

Solution:  Reverse the procedure.
Hold down the Print Screen key first, then hit Ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Ctrl + Print Screen` is not a shortcut in Windows.

`Print Screen` captures the whole screen, without removing the tip text. Adding `Ctrl` doesn't change that.

`Alt + Print Screen` captures only the current window, but removes the tip text.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Snipping Tool.

1. Start Snipping Tool
2. Select the snip type (Window | Rectangular) and click New.
3. Hit Esc key.
4. Get the screen and tip on the display.
5. Press Ctrl+PrtScr now use the normal Snipping tool procedures to take your shot.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Hi Retired Geek & Andre

Perhaps I should retitle my entry:
"How to take a screenshot of an MSAccess ControlTip Text in Form View using the arcane method."

I tried just pressing "Print Screen" and that worked.  Thanks